# Python Scipy truncated exponential distribution

Tags: python, scipy

I need to construct a  truncated exponential random variable, bounded between 5 and 7, with a rate parameter equal to 0.76. I am using scipy.stats.truncexpon, with loc=5 and scale=1/0.76. I am not sure how to specify the upper bound though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lower, upper, scale = 5, 7, 1/0.76
X = stats.truncexpon(b=(upper-lower)/scale, loc=lower, scale=scale)
data = X.rvs(10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, normed=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

`stats.truncexpon` is an [instance of a subclass of `rv_continuous`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L4804).
The `rv_continuous` class has [`a` and `b` parameters which define the lower and upper bound](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L1323) of the support of the distribution. `truncexpon` has the `a` parameter fixed at 0:

```
truncexpon = truncexpon_gen(a=0.0, name='truncexpon')
```

Thus by default `truncexpon`'s support goes from `0` to `b`.
[Per the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncexpon.html),

> `truncexpon.pdf(x, b, loc, scale)` is identically
>   equivalent to `truncexpon.pdf(y, b) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

So as `y` goes from `0` to `b`, `x` goes from `loc` to `b*scale + loc`.
So to make `x` go from `lower` to `upper`, let `loc = lower` and `b = (upper-lower)/scale`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The problem in that when I set the scale to a value other than one, the support for my distribution changes and is no longer from lower to upper (it starts from lower but does not end at upper).

Comment: Right. I've revised the code to take into account a change in scale.